# How to update item of List without modifying its Modified date in SharePoint online with Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I am using Client Object Model to update property of items in a list of SharePoint online. My requirement is to update Title field of item without changing or affecting the modified date of item using Client Object Model.

Thanks
Prakash

Answer (score 1):

The Managed `Client Object Model`  have  `"limitation"` with regards to the way a `List Item` Update works - that is `there is no SystemUpdate type functionality available like in the 'full' SharePoint Object Model.`

What I can suggest is that if you really want this functionality, `write your own custom web service that updates the document metadata using SystemUpdate so a new version isn't created and deploy it to your SharePoint Server`. This will allow you to call your custom web service from your code and will satisfy your requirements.

I hope this helps

Comment: I agree with your solution but is not feasible as the SharePoint server is Microsoft Office 365 where we are not allowed to host our custom web service.

Answer (score 0):

If we Check
ListItem methods regarding Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem_methods.aspx
and

SPListItem Methods regarding Microsoft.SharePoint.

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem_methods.aspx

The method "SysytemUpdate" is only present in Microsoft.SharePoint SPListItem class but not under Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client ListItem class. So, from clent object model we cannot update list data without affecting modifying date.

you can check [client object model](http://adicodes.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010/) post in my blog

Thanks,

Adi

[SharePoint Codes](http://adicodes.wordpress.com/)